# I'm trying to attach input button to bottom of an image

Tags: html, css

I'm trying to make it look like this

[img](https://i.stack.imgur.com/fvcdl.png)

But mine looks like this

```css
.profile-img .file{
position: relative;
overflow: hidden;
margin-top: -20%;
width: 70%;
border: none;
border-radius: 0;
font-size: 15px;
background: #212529b8;
}


 #changephotobar{
  position: relative;
  overflow: hidden;
  margin-top: -20%;
  width: 200%;
  border: none;
  border-radius: 0;
  font-size: 15px;
  background: #212529b8;

 }

 .file input{

  position: absolute !important;
    opacity: 0 !important;
    right: 0 !important;
    top: 0 !important;
}

.btn {
    font-size: 1rem;
    font-weight: 600;
    line-height: 1.5;
    display: inline-block;
    padding: .625rem 1.25rem;
    -webkit-user-select: none;
    -moz-user-select: none;
    -ms-user-select: none;
    user-select: none;
    transition: color .15s ease-in-out, background-color .15s ease-in-out, border-color .15s ease-in-out, box-shadow .15s ease-in-out;
    text-align: center;
    vertical-align: middle;
    white-space: nowrap;
    border: 1px solid transparent;
    border-radius: .375rem;
  }
```

```html
 <a href="#">
                        <img src="https://encrypted-tbn0.gstatic.com/images?q=tbn:ANd9GcQl0CRAYnWtpuyk36YvmLUYRR90kp9aZWLMoS3urAobOIeitTp4CeNSWg43iupNKGCZMKA&usqp=CAU" class="rounded-circle">
                        <div id="changephotobar" class="file btn btn-lg btn-primary">
                                    Change Photo
                                    <input type="file" name="file"/>
                                </div>
                      </a>
                    </div>
```

here's an image of what it exactly looks like in my project

[mine in project](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Anxpe.png)

The issue is i want to attach it to the image responsively so no matter how vertical or horizontal the image is , the bar is still attach at the bottom of the image.. Like the image i showed above.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not entirely sure, but you should add `margin: 20%` instead of `margin: -20%`. I haven't tested this, but you can try it!

Answer (score -1):

Your code is good. But there is a slight mistake. You have to change div tag of #changephotobar to label so that it can trigger your input type file.

Thanks me later.

```css
* {
box-sizing: border-box;
}
.rounded-circle {
width: 50%;
}
.profile-img .file{
position: relative;
overflow: hidden;
margin-top: -20%;
width: 70%;
border: none;
border-radius: 0;
font-size: 15px;
background: #212529b8;
}


 #changephotobar{
  position: relative;
  overflow: hidden;
  margin-top: -20%;
  width: 50%;
  border: none;
  border-radius: 0;
  font-size: 15px;
  background: #212529b8;
  color: #fff;

 }

 .file input{

  position: absolute !important;
    opacity: 0 !important;
    right: 0 !important;
    top: 0 !important;
}

.btn {
    font-size: 1rem;
    font-weight: 600;
    line-height: 1.5;
    display: inline-block;
    padding: .625rem 1.25rem;
    -webkit-user-select: none;
    -moz-user-select: none;
    -ms-user-select: none;
    user-select: none;
    transition: color .15s ease-in-out, background-color .15s ease-in-out, border-color .15s ease-in-out, box-shadow .15s ease-in-out;
    text-align: center;
    vertical-align: middle;
    white-space: nowrap;
    border: 1px solid transparent;
    border-radius: .375rem;
  }
```

```html
<a href="#">
   <img src="https://encrypted-tbn0.gstatic.com/images?q=tbn:ANd9GcQl0CRAYnWtpuyk36YvmLUYRR90kp9aZWLMoS3urAobOIeitTp4CeNSWg43iupNKGCZMKA&usqp=CAU" class="rounded-circle">
   <label id="changephotobar" class="file btn btn-lg btn-primary">
        Change Photo
        <input type="file" name="file"/>
    </label>
</a>
```

Comment: Didn't work unfortunately, Made things worse , Thank you though.